# How to identify source of specific dependency in SBT

Tags: scala, junit, dependencies, sbt

When running an SBT compile, I can see a specific dependency with a specific version coming in in the build log:

```
[info] Resolving junit#junit;4.12 ...
```

This dependency is not mentioned explicity in any of the build.sbt files, so it is either coming in as a transitive dependency or maybe from the Play framework itself.

Any idea how I can trace the exact source of this particular Junit version dependency? I have already tried to get it from the SBT dependency tree. However, this includes only the same "Resolving..." msg, but not where it's been resolved from.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before there was a plugin for inspecting dependencies: [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dependency-graph). Now (since sbt 1.4) it's part of the core sbt and can be enabled by adding `addDependencyTreePlugin` to your `project/plugins.sbt` file. Then you can use commands like `whatDependsOn`:

> `whatDependsOn <organization> <module> <revision>?`: Find out what depends on an artifact. Shows a reverse dependency tree for the selected module. The `<revision>` argument is optional.

Or, if it doesn't help, run `dependencyBrowseGraph` or `dependencyBrowseTree`, and inspect the graph/tree (there is a search field).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. I was aware of the `dependencyBrowse ...` commands, but in my case it didn't help, because of the huge dependency tree. For me, the `whatDependsOn` task only works from the sbt shell by entering `$ whatDependsOn junit junit 4.12` at the prompt. This works, but the output is not very helpful, as it merely lists general dependencies and version conflicts.

Comment: Please, add output of `whatDependsOn ...` to your question and explain how it is different from what you expect to see